# How to preserve properties (like -p) in topojson conversion in Mapshaper?

Tags: tools, topojson, mapshaper

I'm trying to use [mapshaper.org](http://www.mapshaper.org/) to convert some geojson files to topojson, and I need the identifying properties to be preserved.

Normally this would be done [with the `-p` flag on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095316/topojson-properties-preservation), but despite mapshaper having the facility to allow "options from the command line interface", I can't get it to work.

I've tried `-p identifier-name` which give the error:

> Unknown command: p

...and I've tried I've tried `"-p identifier-name"` in quotes following the help examples which give the error:

> Unknown output option: -p identifier-name

---

Update: I've figured out that Mapshaper isn't passing these commands to the normal `topojson` tool, it's using them in its own custom command line interface, which is [documented here](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference) (strangely there don't seem to be any links to this in Mapshaper itself).

In theory I want the option `"id-field=nameoffield"` but it doesn't seem to make any difference - all the geojson properties are still appended to the end of the file and the named property is not changed to an identifier.

How can I filter the properties in Mapshaper like I would with the command `topojson in.json -o out.json -p prop1,prop2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with the following in Mapshaper's "command line options" box on the Export window:

```
"id-field=NameOfField" "drop-table"
```

Mapshaper doesn't pass the commands to the normal `topojson` tool, it has its own command line interface which is documented [on the Github page here](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference).

<sub>If there's a link to this on Mapshaper itself, I can't find it, please edit where it is into my answer!</sub>

It seems like you need to `drop-table` all the properties to get one to stand alone as an ID field. I can't find any way to preserve multiple properties while removing the others, or to preserve properties' names, but this works for my needs. Output looks like:

```
{"type":"Topology",
  "transform":{"scale":[0.XX,0.XX],"translate":[-X.XX,X.XX]},
  "arcs":[[[XX,XX],[XX,XX],[XX,XX],[XX,XX],[XX,XX],[XX,XX],[XX,XX],[XX,XX],[XX,XX],[XX,XX],[XX,XX],[XX,XX],...continues...
  "objects":{
     "filename":{
        "type":"GeometryCollection",
           "geometries":[
              {"arcs":[[0,1,2...]],"type":"Polygon","id":"Contents of NameOfField #0 here"},
              {"arcs":[[X,X,X...]],"type":"Polygon","id":"Contents of NameOfField #1 here"},
              ...continues...
```

Comment: Closest way to get multiple properties I've found so far is to use [a composite id field with a separator](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233438/export-topojson-from-mapshaper-with-an-id-field-that-is-a-composite-created-from), like `id#_code_name` in the topojson then split them out on the processing side. Not ideal but it's an option.