# Export topojson from Mapshaper with an ID field that is a composite created from multiple fields

Tags: mapshaper

I've got some GIS data with many data fields for each feature. I'm using Mapshaper to simplify it into a light, lean topojson file.

I want the ID fields of these features in the output to be a modified composite of different fields, for example: `fieldA_fieldB`.

I've tried putting an expression in the **export** option:

```
"drop table" "id-field=fieldA+'_'+fieldB"
```

...but it didn't work. I can't immediately see anything in the [command reference](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference#-each) to do what I want to do.

---

For bonus points I'd also like to run an expression over the field to modify it in other ways, for example, one of my fields is a 3-digit number with preceding zeros (e.g. `092`) and if possible I'd like to remove these while creating the topojson, e.g. taking `092` and `someName` and outputting the ID field as `92_someName`. If this isn't possible in Mapshaper I can work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `-each` command](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference#user-content--each) to create a new field for each feature in the currently selected layer based on a javascript expression running on that feature's data which has access to all its field data.

Here's a simple example that creates a field like `new_field    'field-data-A_field-data-B'`. Get the (case sensitive) names of the fields you want by using `-info`:

```
-each "new_field = fieldA + '_' + fieldB"
```

Then, once you've got that field, you can export it as an ID field with something like this in the **export** feature:

```
"id-field=new_field" "drop-table"
```

---

Since it's a javascript expression, you can do almost any transformation on the field data, such as regular expression, mathematical operations, etc. So for example, for the example of stripping preceding zeros from a `fieldA` with values like `004`, I could simply convert it from a string to a number then back again:

```
-each "new_field = parseFloat( fieldA ) + '_' + fieldB"
```

Comment: There's no other way to add custom attributes to the export? Currently I'm doing this then using find & replace to split them apart into separate attributes `data-name` `class` and `id`